# Why is my external SSD not recognized?

Tags: linux, usb, manjaro, ssd, parrotsec

Okay so. I am running Manjaro on my [Lenovo Ideapad 300-15IBR](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/300-series/300-15ibr) and I bought an  external SSD.

When I plug it in to the laptop, it works; I can read and write files on it, on USB 3.0 and USB 2.0.

Problem is when I try to boot from it. It is not recognized in BIOS nor Boot Menu when I plug it in USB 3.0, but it works in 2.0 BIOS recognize it.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Thank you

**EDIT**

Command:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | sudo grep "model name" && sudo lshw | sudo grep -A5 "Moth" && sudo lshw | sudo grep product | sudo head -n1
```

Output":

```
model name      : Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3710  @ 1.60GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3710  @ 1.60GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3710  @ 1.60GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3710  @ 1.60GHz

    description: Motherboard
    product: Paris G 5A6
    vendor: LENOVO
    physical id: 0
    version: NO DPK
    serial: PF0HH105
    product: 80M3 (LENOVO_MT_80M3_BU_idea_FM_Lenovo ideapad 300-15IBR)
```

SSD is Western Digital's My-Passport of 256GB.

**UPDATE 2**

I made it work. I just used another USB cable for it and it was present in BIOS and Boot Menu. But now I am facing another problem.

I have Parrot OS on this external SSD. It boots up. Presents Parrot's loading screen and then I get 3 messages

```
[5.797031] scsi 2:0:0:1: Wrong diagnostic page: asked for 1 got 0
[5.797374] scsi 2:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
[5.797424] scsi 2:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
```

After this I get only black screen and nothing else.

Comment: May I please ask for the model number of the My Passport drive? Western Digital has made many.

Comment: So it's recognized by your Manjaro OS when plugging it in via USB and USB3 and you can read and write but when you try to boot from it, it's not recognized by the BIOS or boot menu if it's connected to USB3 but it is if connected to USB2. If you can read and write to it with USB3 then I don't see how the BIOS isn't recognizing it because it would have to in order for the OS to see it.

Comment: Model number is WDBKVX2560PSL.

Comment: And as of second comment. I am confused to. Because BIOS sees it from USB 2.0..

Comment: Which OS is installed on your external SSD? Did you create the partitions manually?

Comment: Parrot OS. I used guided partitioning for it

Answer (score 0):

**REPLY TO UPDATE 2**

First off, this should really be a new question at this point.

Anyway, try an fsck on the disk to make sure the filesystem is good.
If it is, you could try to reinstall to the drive. It could also be a hardware problem with the drive itself.

**Original:**

First off, there could be an option like 'USB 3.0 Boot' or 'USB 3.0 Legacy Boot' in your BIOS/UEFI settings. Check for something like that.

Barring that, the following could or could not be applicable to your machine:

If it boots in USB 2.0 but not 3.0, it could just be that the 3.0 ports are being hosted via a chip that the BIOS isn't aware of. My Thinkpad X201 has USB 3.0 ports controlled via an NEC uPD720202 chip, which is of course external to the Intel chipset that the BIOS has been programmed to know about and control. Thus, from a booted system with the right drivers, I can access the USB3 ports, but I can't from the BIOS because it isn't aware of the ports at that point.

Some other machines have USB 3 provided by an *on-board* NEC/Renesas chip, which would similarly not be read. And if it's on an ExpressCard or something, it is almost definitely not going to boot from USB3.

Comment: I disabled legacy boot and still the same. Also enabled it and still no luck. I tried every option in it but it couls be possible that bios isn't aware of it on the boot.

Comment: My question is. Is there any way to turn on system from external SSD on port 3.0? Something like turning on PC and then thurning it on from SSD there. Idk..

Comment: @Mileta Dulovic Could just be your BIOS doesn't know about the USB 3 controller. You may be stuck using a USB 2.x port. I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: @Wyatt8704 I updated the question above. I made it worl but now I am facing different problem

Comment: @MiletaDulovic Updated.